# How to add same id quantity in below arrays using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have two arrays which are

```
product_id = [5,5,10,15,5,15,22]
product_qty = [58,40,120,100,98,100,50]
```

(I have stored to array as sequence from table. id and quantity orders are same as i mentioned above.)

I want to calculate the same id's total quantity with their id. Result should be

```
result_id = [5,10,15,22] //no duplicates
result_qty = [196,120,200,50] //sum to same id's quantity
```

how to solve this issue in javascript?

Comment: How to know which quantity is for which id? is it the sequence?

Comment: i have stored to array as sequence from table. id and quantity orders are same as i mentioned above

Comment: And how are you generating this array?

Comment: $(data).each(function(did,value){
    var product_place_id = value.product_place_id_primary;
    var ids = getProductAndPlaceId(product_place_id);
    store_product_id.push(ids[0]);
    quantity.push(value.quantity);                              
                        });

Comment: i could take the unique id using sort method. such as

Comment: You need array for this ? You can use hash to store the data in key value pair. `ID` will be the key. If `ID` exists in hash, then perform addition of quantities else create a new entry in hash

Comment: This looks a lot like homework :P

Comment: @VigneswaranMarimuthu can you give me a sample code in order to take unique id and their quantity?

Answer (score 1):

One possible solution (keeping the two array solution as specified in the question, although you may want to look into a hash as specified by Vineswaran in the comments) is to traverse the first array (with the ids) and push the value if it doesn't exist in the index array, or add the value if it exists in the index array, like this:

```js
var product_id = [5,5,10,15,5,15,22];
var product_qty = [58,40,120,100,98,100,50];

var result_id = [];
var result_qty = [];

// traverse the product ids array
$.each(product_id, function(idx, val) {
    // check if that product id had a previous instance
    var auxIdx = $.inArray(val, result_id)
    if (auxIdx >= 0) {
        // if it did, add the quantities
        result_qty[auxIdx] += product_qty[idx];
    } else {
        // if it didn't, push both id and quantity into the result arrays
        result_id.push(val);
        result_qty.push(product_qty[idx]);
    }
});

console.log(result_id);
console.log(result_qty);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

You can see it on this JSFiddle too: http://jsfiddle.net/pmkLcLdd/

Comment: why does quantity come out like ["584098", "120", "100100", "50"]

Comment: ok bro it's solved

i want to parse the quantity value as integer using parseInt()..

Answer (score 0):

I don't have your sample data. So, i have modified your code in the comment.

```
var store_product = {}; 

$(data).each(function(did,value){
        var product_place_id = value.product_place_id_primary;
        var ids = getProductAndPlaceId(product_place_id);

        var item_quantity = store_product[ids[0]];

        if (item_quantity) {
            store_product[ids[0]] = (item_quantity + value.quantity);
        } else {
            store_product[ids[0]] = value.quantity;
        }
    });
```

`store_product` hash will have your expected result. You can convert it into array or anything as per your needs.

Answer (score 0):

**I think an object would be better suited for what you want as a result**, this way, you can easily relate an `id` to its `quantity`, with the `id` being the key:

```
var product_id = [5,5,10,15,5,15,22],
    product_qty = [58,40,120,100,98,100,50],
    result_qty = {};

product_qty.forEach(function (qty, i) {
    var indexVal = result_qty[product_id[i]] || 0;
    result_qty[product_id[i]] = indexVal + qty;
});

console.log(result_qty); 
// Logs Object {5: 196, 10: 120, 15: 200, 22: 50}

console.log(result_qty[5]);
// Logs 196

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////
// * However, if you really want both, the ids and quantities in
// * array format, then it's just a matter of running this,
// * after the previous code:

var tmp = [],
    result_id = [];

// * (looping through the object)
for(var prop in result_qty) {
    if(result_qty.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
        tmp.push(result_qty[prop]);
        result_id.push(parseInt(prop, 10));
    }
}
result_qty = tmp;

console.log(result_id);
// Logs [196, 120, 200, 50]
console.log(result_qty);
// Logs [5, 10, 15, 22]
```

I've included a way to get the arrays anyway, so you have both options.

Answer (score 0):

you don't need jquery for this

```js
var product_id = [5,5,10,15,5,15,22]
var product_qty = [58,40,120,100,98,100,50]

var result_id = product_id.slice(); //Copy arrays
var result_qty = product_qty.slice()

var i = result_id.length;
while(i > 0){
  var id = result_id.shift();              //remove first element
  --i;
  var sum = result_qty.shift();            //init sum count
  var index = result_id.indexOf(id, 0);    //find next match of element
  while(index != -1){
    result_id.splice(index, 1);            //remove element in index
    --i;
    sum += result_qty.splice(index, 1)[0]; //index 0, since splice return a list with length 1
    index = result_id.indexOf(id,index);
  }
  result_id.push(id);                      //add to end
  result_qty.push(sum);
}

console.log(result_id);
console.log(result_qty);
```

```html
<script src="http://gh-canon.github.io/stack-snippet-console/console.min.js"></script>
```